# SQL PowerShell Snapin Problems

Tags: powershell, sql

I am hoping this is an easy fix and oversight on my part. I need to be able to run the SQL cmdlets from remote machines. I have installed Microsoft® Windows PowerShell Extensions for SQL Server® 2008 R2 (along with the other requirements), however when I try to add the pssnapin I receive the error that the snap-in is not installed on this computer.

Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'SqlServerCmdletSnapin100' is not installed on this computer.

Any help?

Thank

Comment: Try running "Get-PSSnapin -Registered" to confirm what snap-ins are installed. It's possible the snapin is called something slightly different.

Also, if you are on a 64-bit OS, trying running a 32-bit instance of PowerShell and see if "Get-PSSnapin -Registered" shows the snap-in there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So something odd, the SQL PSSnapins load fine in the 64-bit console, but give me the error "Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'SqlServerCmdletSnapin100' is not installed on this computer" when trying to load in the 32-bit. I really need to load these in both. Is it possible to get them loaded into both?

Comment: It looks like the easiest thing to do would be to install the PowerShellTools.msi file from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580
This installs the latest version of SQLps as a module that is usable by both 32-bit and 64-bit PowerShell.

Comment: I've installed that, but still get the same error :(

Answer (score 2):

If you installed the 2012 PowerShellTools.msi, then you need to reference SqlServerCmdletSnapin**110** (you are specifying SqlServerCmdletSnapin**100**).

Also - it appears sometimes you have to register the DLLs even after running the Power ShellTools.msi install.  Take a look at this post for details:

https://markcz.wordpress.com/2009/12/19/how-to-register-powershell-sql-server-snapin-in-windows-preinstalled-powershell/

Note that the path to the `installutil` may vary depending on what version(s) of the .NET framework you have installed and the path to the DLLs will vary depending on which version of the tools you installed.  I have .NET 4, and the 2012 64-bit PowerShell tools installed, so here was what worked for me:

```
set-alias installutil $env:windir\microsoft.net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil

installutil -i "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider.dll"

installutil -i "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll"
```

Given this is such an old post, you probably already got this resolved or found a workaround, but wanted to offer a solution for any folks that run into the problem in the future.